# Error showing undefined in calling soap xml in javascript

Tags: jquery, xml, soap

i am developing an apps that need to call a soap xml which displays data without passing any parameters using jquery, but i keep on getting 'error'
this is my code

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$.support.cors = true;
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnh").click(function (event) {
                var webserUrl = 'http://localhost/googlesearch/service1.asmx?op=SearchString';

                var soapRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
<soap:Body> \
<SearchString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /> \
</soap:Body> \
 </soap:Envelope>';
                alert(soapRequest);
                soapRequest = $.trim(soapRequest);
                alert(soapRequest);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: webserUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    processData: false,
                    data: soapRequest,
                    success: function (data, status, req) {
                    if (status == "success")
                        alert(req.responseText);
                },
                error: function (data, status, req) {

                    alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
                }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Note: On checking browser console it shows "Method not found"

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Shaun "Undefined error"

Comment: Could you possibly be using a service that no longer exists? [The Google SOAP Search API is no longer available](https://developers.google.com/soap-search/?csw=1)